# Install Vue 2 in a Phoenix 1.4 Application with Webpack 4

Tags: vue.js, phoenix-framework, webpack-4

I want to install Vue 2 in a new Phoenix 1.4 project.

I am using Webpack 4. The documentation for Vue does not provide much guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Install Vue:

`cd assets/`

`npm install vue vue-loader vue-template-compiler --save`

In `webpack.config.js` add the following lines where appropriate, heeding existing configuration:

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
    },  
  },
```

This Webpack config will need to be merged with what is already shipped with your Phoenix project.

Create a folder for your Vue components (i.e., your `.vue` files):

`mkdir js/components/`

In `assets/js/app.js` add:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const files = require.context('./components/', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
  });
});
```

Be sure to add an `#app` ID to an element somewhere in your layout.

Comment: This is how I managed to get Vue working; however, I am unsure if it is best practice. As I mentioned in my question, there did not seem to be much guidance in the Vue documentation on how to install using Webpack, so if somebody knows of any official documentation, that would be appreciated.